# Period of $|\sin x|$ for Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I was doing Fourier series problem sets but encountered a rather surprising "problem".

The first problem stated:

> Find the Fourier series for $f(x)=|\sin x|$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Thus, the implied period of the function that I used for calculations later on was $2\pi$. The second didn't specify an interval, so I used $\pi$, but the actual period of $|\sin(x)|$ is just $\pi$.

Is it because in the problem it said "$-\pi < x < \pi$" the reason one must use $2\pi $ as a period? This changes the angular frequency ($1$ for period $\pi$ and $2$ for period $2\pi$). Or is there another reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, the reason the period of the function is $\;\pi\;$ is because (using trigonometric identity)

$$\sin(x+\pi)=\sin x\cos \pi+\sin \pi\cos x=-\sin x\implies$$

$$|\sin(x+\pi)|=|-\sin x|=|\sin x|$$

Comment: It was more along the lines why we use 2pi the first time and 1pi the second time? Because in the solution the author uses 2pi as a period (for when x is between -pi and pi).

Comment: @tummath if $\;k\;$ is **the** period for some function, then *any* integer multiple of $\;k\;$ is  **a** period, so the author *perhaps* wanted to work, for some reason, with $\;2\pi\;$ instead of $\;\pi\;$